# Survey with multiple selections per matrix row and two qualitative axes (words instead of 'rating scale')

Tags: survey, multiple-values, multi-select

As per picture example, I have some categories that are sufficiently closely related as not to warrant individual multiple choice questions for each row (that would lead to a lot of repetition, and scare off the respondents). I don't really know my way around SharePoint, but I'm ready to entertain responses that venture into JavaScript / .aspx editing (though some hand-holding would be required).

[image: multiple choice qualitative matrix]

Comment: what version of sharepoint are you using?